# Problem writing HTML file to Confluence using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a pandas dataframe to an html file. And now I want to write the contents of that file to confluence.

I am able to log into confluence and write to it with my script, but the contents on the page are the word 'None' instead of the contents of the file. And if I print the type of the variable that holds the name of the file it comes back with: `<class 'NoneType'>`

```
def authenticate():
    auth = get_login()
    return auth

def export_file()
    import pandas,pathlib
    auth = authenticate()
    pageid = 11111111
    title = 'GCP Instance List'
    output_dir = os.path.join("..", "..", "output_files", "gcp_instance_list", "html", "")
    output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, "gcp-instance-list.html")
    html_file = docs.to_html(output_file)
    path = pathlib.Path(output_file)
    if path.exists():
        return html_file
        print(type(html_file))
        write_data_to_confluence(auth,html_file,padeid,title)
    else:
        print("HTML file has not been created.")
```

I've manually opened up the HTML file I'm creating in chrome and the results look exactly right.

How can I write the contents of the file instead of the incorrect 'None' type to a confluence page?

Comment: this line `html_file = docs.to_html(output_file)` saves the file to disk and its return type is None, I think this is causing the problem. try this `html_file  = docs.to_html()` considering doc is your dataframe.

Comment: two ways, one you can open the HTML you have saved, and then send that one; the other way is `html_file  = docs.to_html()` i.e (do not pass disk file parameter) it will return you HTML and then pass this.

Comment: OK thanks, I tried  `html_file = docs.to_html()` and passing that and it just writes an empty table to confluence. I can try your other suggestion of opening the file next and returning that.

Comment: Ok I tried opening the file with `html_file = open(output_file)` and returning that, but now I get a stack trace that says: `HTTP Status Code: 400
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gcp_list_instances.py", line 373, in <module>
    main()
  File "gcp_list_instances.py", line 368, in main
    write_data_to_confluence(auth, html_file, pageid, title)
  File "gcp_list_instances.py", line 235, in write_data_to_confluence
    raise RuntimeError(r.content)`

Comment: continuation of the stack trace: `RuntimeError: b'{"statusCode":400,"data":{"authorized":false,"valid":true,"allowedInReadOnlyMode":true,"errors":[],"successful":false},"message":"Error parsing xhtml: Unexpected close tag </xml>; expected </_io.TextIOWrapper>.\\n at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,466]","reason":"Bad Request"}'`

Comment: can you share the HTML source, I mean open it in a text editor and share some. I feel that it has escape characters that function `write_data_to_confluence` is not liking.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me and sorry for the delay! I had to be real careful about how I anonymized this data using completely fake hostnames and blotting out IPs. But the complete structure of the HTML is there. See below for my html:

Comment: `<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Instance ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Network Interfaces</th>
      <th>Timestamp</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>123456789101110131416</td>
      <td>anon-host1</td>
      <td>xx.xx.xx.xx</td>
      <td>2021-01-28T12:37:21.416-08:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>12345678910111213145</td>
      <td>anon-host2</td>
      <td>xx.xx.xx.xx</td>
      <td>2021-01-28T11:13:57.519-08:00</td>`

Comment: `</tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>`

Comment: you would need to compare and debug your current HTML with the HTML which is successful. for example, as data frame(pandas) created the table it missed the `!DOCTYPE`, and other HTML tags which are mostly needed if looking for xhtml.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try doing that!

Comment: Here's an example of some output that would post to confluence at my old company. I don't see any important difference! It's from my personal lab, and all the servers in the list are either deleted or stopped. So I didn't bother anonymizing any data: https://pastebin.com/gy7Fw96L

Comment: I've got it sorted! What I did was open the file for reading in the `write_data_to_confluence` function. And now the HTML posts to confluence no problem. SWEET! Many thanks for your help and replies!

Comment: that's awesome! glad that its resolved now :)

Comment: Cool. Again, I appreciate the help. Have a good one!